# Threading functions

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

Is there a simpler way to achieve threading functionality in racket? I know about the threading library but it seems like such a basic functionality that I wonder if there is not some builtin way to do this.

```
(define (thread x . fns)
    (foldl (lambda (f a) (f a))
           thread
           fns))
```

Also, can you express `(lambda (f a) (f a))` in a simpler fashion?

Comment: did you mean to use `x` as the starting value in the foldl?

Comment: Your `thread` works (provided that you fix the mistake the @AlexKnauth pointed out). But there are three reasons why you might prefer the threading library. 1) yours has a runtime overhead. The library uses macro to avoid that (as @tfb pointed out below) 2) the library allows you to thread arbitrary form (i.e., syntax), not just function value 3) it provides a nice support for "currying".

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways of doing this.  A nice one is to use a macro, a simple (and perhaps not completely correct) version of which is:

```
(define-syntax (/> stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ x)
     #'x]
    [(_ x f)
     #'(f x)]
    [(/> x f fs ...)
     #'(/> (f x) fs ...)]
    [/>
     (identifier? #'/>)
     #'(λ (x . fns)
         (for/fold ([r x]) ([f fns])
           (f r)))]))
```

Now, for instance `(/> x sin cos)` is expanded to `(cos (sin x))`: there is no run-time overhead at all.  The last clause means that `(apply /> 1 (list sin cos))` will work.

I'm not *sure* the above macro is completely correct, particularly the last clause.

Comment: On that last clause, I would recommend that you lift that lambda out of the syntax definition. Define it as a normal function, then expand to that function name instead of expanding to a new copy of the lambda expression every time

Comment: @AlexKnauth: I think that's optimizing an idle loop. The function is consed once per macroexpansion (so, almost never), in a case which almost never happens, in code which was only meant as a demonstration!

Comment: It's just a good habit to develop for macros-that-are-also-functions in general, especially if the function you're expanding to has other macro uses within it which will be re-expanded, easily avoidable

Comment: @AlexKnauth: thanks for teaching me me about 'good habits'.  All those years and I never knew any.